# Can someone explain this program?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Prod{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(prod(1, 4));
    }

    public static int prod(int m, int n) {
        if (m == n) {
            return n;
        } else {
            int recurse = prod(m, n-1);
            int result = n * recurse;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I've read a solution here: [JAVA Recursive Program logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992138/java-recursive-program-logic) that makes some sense but I don't get why when it hits prod(1,1) it goes back to prod(1,2)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `System.out.println(prod(1,4));` and go step by step, you'll get how recursion works.....and do you know why your question got downvoted?  SO is for solving bugs/issues in the code not for gettting explaination of how the code work...

Answer (score 0):

It will return the factorial of `n` with min limit `m`. Like

```
n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) * (n-4) * (n-5) ... till (n-x) != m
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it has `prod(1,2`) and other methods in the stack. Each time `prod(m,n)` is called it recursively calls `prod(m,n-1)` . This continues till `m==n` , in your case `prod(1,1)`. Here `prod(1,1)` will return value to the calling method `prod(1,2)`

```
    //method prod(1,2)
          ....
     int recurse = prod(m, n-1);//here it will get value 1 returned from prod(1,1)
     int result = n * recurse; // 2*1
     return result; // return 2 to calling method prod(1,3)
```

So when finally recursive call ends at `prod(1,1)` and returns values. all the previous `prod()` present in the call stack will be execute each one getting return from called `prod(m,n-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Let's add logging with some [formatted output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and I'd suggest you use a [Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) like

```
public static int prod(int m, int n) {
    int recurse = (n != m) ? prod(m, n - 1) : 1;
    int r = n * recurse;
    System.out.printf("m=%d, n=%d, recurse = %d, returning %d%n", m, n,
            recurse, r);
    return r;
}
```

Output should explain your result

```
m=1, n=1, returning 1
m=1, n=2, recurse = 1, returning 2
m=1, n=3, recurse = 2, returning 6
m=1, n=4, recurse = 6, returning 24
24
```